# Pass size from mebedded UIViewController to parent container

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

How to set up constraints to **make parent container view frame dynamic, dependent on frame of embedded view**?

My situation is following: I placed `UIView` container with embedded `UIViewController`. That embedded view should resize parent container based on it's frame. I stuck with setting up constraints, because the root view of embedded view controller can't own size constraints (instead it has autoresizing mask). I could pass needed values in code via custom properties, but it's ugly workaround in so beautiful autolayout world :)

So is there a way to set up autolayout so container view frame is defined by embedded one? If it can be done just in `Interface Builder`, would be perfect.

*Update: added screenshot*
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you take some screenshot of your storyboard? I guess in your case use an `UIView` is better than use a container, since container should have premade size

Comment: @Tj3n, I added screenshot. It's typical scene. Maybe we can somehow set container constraints priority to low, so autolayout engine will take embedded view constraints to define the frame... In my case I can't set up constraints for root view of embedded view controller.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use container? container is viewcontroller and it have no size, if yours is dynamic better just use custom uiview, and you are already giving it constrained height and width

Comment: @Tj3n, container is a good way to store overlaying views separately. I could place embedded view directly in main view controller, but in that case it would be uncomfortable to deal with underlying UI. That's why I'm looking for elegant approach for my situation.